# The type or namespace name 'ViewModels' does not exist in the namespace 'Plugin1'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, plugins, mef

I 'm using [this](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/06/17/Revised-ASPNET-MVC-and-the-Managed-Extensibility-Framework-%28MEF%29.aspx) approach to implement a pluggable architecture in a proof of concept application (ASP.NET MVC 3, using Razor **& strongly typed views**).

So: i have a normal ASP.NET MVC3 project and a Classlibrary project (the Plugin).

Everything went fine, but as soon as i used strongly typed views (in the Plugin project) i got the following error:

```
CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ViewModels' does not exist in the namespace 'Plugin1' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

The namespace exists in this assembly, but i have the slight feeling ... somehow it is not loaded...

What do i miss??

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to the plugin project in `Web.config`.

Comment: Are you sure? Isn't this against the principles of using MEF? Why should i reference the Plugin project? And how do i know how many Plugin projects will be developed in the future?...? Shouldn't this work dynamically?